# Extracting Meaning from a Sentence Using NLP

Tags: nlp

Basically I am trying to take answer of question why from sentence.

Example Sentence: I uninstalled the app because it really drains my battery.

Example Output: Why user uninstalled the app? -> Because it drains her/his battery.

My researches didn't lead me to a place where I can work on. What should I do/use to achieve this. Anyone can show me a path?

Comment: What you've described is a lot more specific than "extracting meaning". It sounds like you're trying to transform a statement into a question and an answer. This answer goes over part of that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55243829/how-to-convert-sentence-to-question-using-spacy-library-in-python-refer-my-code

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert in NLP but I have some preliminary concepts, that is for this type of problem first you need to have a dataset and it should be appropriately tagged if you can find a dataset relevant to your problem the rest should follow through.